# Expose SuggestedEditVotes in the data dump

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, data-dump

I'd like to use the SuggestedEditVotes table (which is available in [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com)) to find robo-reviewers. I'm often offline without connection to SEDE, and I want to do something remotely productive during those times. I'd like to have the table locally.

I could run a bunch of paged queries, downloading all [3.4 million](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/178120) of them 50,000 at a time - but I have this idea that SE might not like that.

Can we please add the SuggestedEditVotes table to the data dump? It would be [nice to have the SuggestedEdits table too](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14463526#14463526), but it's not strictly necessary for my purposes. But if you're going to touch the data dumps anyway...

Comment: 3 407 628 items / 50 000 items per page = a mere 69 pages. Spread it out over a few days and you really should (IMO) be okay.

Comment: @michael Yeah, thought of that. Two things: (1) it's hacky, and (2) I'm a programmer, so I would have to write something to automatically do it. That would take way longer than two days.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1319/